# Is there an html tag that will make text scroll across a page?

Tags: html, css

So I want to make an orange scrolling text bar that I am going to place at the top of my web site. I just finished learning how to put the styles inside of html tags. I was wondering if there was a way to do this like that. I am really new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included the styling inside of the div tag below as you requested but I would highly encourage you to move that style into an external stylesheet once you have reviewed how that works I can also give you some tutorial instructions to help you learn how to create an external style sheet.

```
<!-- Alert Bar -->
    <div class="marqueeWrapper" style="background-color: #D35400; height: 25px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; z-index: 300; width: 100%;">
    <p style="color: #FFF;">
    <marquee>Here is your marquee example edit this text</marquee>
    </p>
    </div>
<!-- Alert Bar ends -->
```

Comment: Where would I put my external stylesheet in my html?

Comment: Inside of your head tags and make sure to place your stylesheet in the same folder as your index.html page or your browser will not be able to locate it with <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>

Comment: Wow `marquee` still works??? I assumed it had been deprecated like the blink tag...

Comment: Yes its kind of nifty if you want a simple banner for showing alerts like if your business is closed or tornado warning etc

Comment: Heh. Long live the 90's I guess. I agree, its super useful. I just assumed that CSS animation had replaced it long ago. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯